# How to handle BouncyCastle change and test Android system upgrade?

Tags: android, bouncycastle

My application is dependent on BouncyCastle library. When system is upgraded to 2.3, version of this library is also upgraded. So when user upgrades system all of data that was encrypted can not be decrypted anymore.

First question - can I somehow avoid this situation? Be able to decrypt even after upgrade.

Second - How to simulate system upgrade to check if my code that says "sorry for your data loss" works?

To be more precise, this code, for the same seed, in different versions of OS ( before 2.3 and since 2.3) generates different keys:

```
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
sr.setSeed(seed);
kgen.init(128, sr);
SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
raw = skey.getEncoded();
```

Comment: You should explain what you do exactly, there should be backward compatibility...

Comment: As I said, I have lots of data that is kept in encrypted form. After upgrade, when the random number generator has changed, the data seems to be corrupted after decryption attempt.

Comment: Wait... You used the random number generator as a stream cipher? For any sane crypto practice the RNG implementation changing shouldn't have any effects whatsoever...